# Center Span Over Div Button

Tags: html, css, html-table, center, centering

I have a div button that I was created through a PayPal integration and I have some text in a span that I would all like to align under my checkout button. The issue is that I can't seem to align the text over the button while keeping them within the same div. Image attached for loads of reference. What would be the best way to achieve this centering without splitting them up?

[Dev view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDbBC.png)

Edit:

Here is the code as things currently stand:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="pull-left"><a href="{{shop.url}}" class="btn btn-default">{{'cart.general.continue_shopping' | t}}</a></div>
{%- if additional_checkout_buttons -%}
<div class="pull-right" id="additional-checkout-buttons" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 8.4px;">
  <span id="additional-checkout-buttons-label" style="margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 10.5px; display: inline-block;">{{'cart.general.checkout_using' | t}}:</span>
  {{content_for_additional_checkout_buttons}}
</div>
{%- endif -%}

 <div class="pull-right"><input type="submit" name="checkout" id="update-cart" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{'cart.general.checkout' | t}}" /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi can you add you code please. thanks

Comment: adding your code would be helpful.

Comment: Please add some code, then we can help you!

Comment: .pull-right{float:none!important; text-align:center;}  Try this. Else add your code here

Answer (score 0):

After referencing your image, it looks like there is a 100% width on the .float-right div. I would change the width settings and make the container inherit the width of the children:

```
.float-right {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: initial; 
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Adding text-align: center to the .float-right div should center the span and button inside the div.

The reason why the .float-right div can't be 100% width is because you want to center both elements inside a width that is maximum as wide as the paypal button - so that the span aligns over the button nicely.

Here is the full snippet:

```css
.float-right {
  float: right !important;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="float-right" id="additional-checkout-buttons" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 8.4px; display: inline-block; width: initial; text-align: center;">
  <span id="additional-checkout-buttons-label">Or checkout using:</span>
  <div class="additional-checkout-button additional-checkout-button--paypal" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <button type="button">Paypal button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a side note,  if width: initial doesn't want to play along, you could always add a fixed width to the .float-right div. But that would not be my first choice.